# How to Login or initiate customer session after Social Login in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I want to facilitate customer to login my Shopify site using their social media accounts.

But I am not really sure how can I start their session after they successfully pass oAuth with their social accounts.

Once they pass the oAuth process I will create customer using Admin API of shopify. but after successfully created customers how can I logged In them.

there is something I might be missing. because there are lots off social login apps available on marketplace.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create customer with random password in shopify store using admin api.

After that you need to login manually by submitting shopify customer login form with the created customer email/password.

This is the only way and everyone is following this way.

Only shopify plus merchants can use multipass option which is really awesome.