# How can I add sign in with google or facebook without using any apps in Shopify?

Tags: jquery, shopify, facebook-login, liquid, google-signin

I am creating custom social signup and social sign in feature in my custom shopify theme through which a user can create an account and can login to view their profile like past orders, address, etc.

I do know about

- [Google sign in button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web)
- [Facebook login button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)

What is the flow to register through email, then enable users to log in with that same email?

Comment: Please go through the below question that might help you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552625/how-to-login-or-initiate-customer-session-after-social-login-in-shopify

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that for any Shopify store unless it is on the Plus plan. Then and only then do you get the Multi-pass login options you seek. So unless your merchant is on plus, your login with Google or Facebook is a pipedream.

Comment: Okay, I did understand about it. So, can I add social login by using shopify social login apps than ?